# Is graphene a better thermal conductor than diamond?

Tags: thermal-conductivity, graphene, diamond

I was listening to the BBC Inside Science Podcast episode about artificial diamonds and they mentioned that diamonds are the most thermally conductive material. One of the people on the episode was cutting an ice cube with a thin piece of diamond (described as being the shape and size of a credit card), which reminded me of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5dwdZCKBZM) of ice being cut with graphene. Both the podcast and some of the places I've searched online say that diamond is the most thermally conductive material, but I'm wondering if that statement is now outdated. The [Wikipedia page on diamonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_properties_of_diamond#Thermal_conductivity) lists the maximum thermal conductivity of diamond as 3320 W/(m·K). The [Wikipedia page for graphene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene#Thermal_conductivity) lists an experimental result of 5300 W/(mK). [This page](https://www.graphene-info.com/graphene-thermal) lists an upper range of 4000 W/(mK).

So is graphene the new king of thermal conductivity, or are those numbers just experimental results?

Comment: In the same wp article, next sentence: However, later studies have questioned whether this ultrahigh value had been overestimated, and have instead measured a wide range of thermal conductivities between 1500 – 2500 W⋅m−1⋅K−1 for suspended single layer graphene.[138][139][140][141]

Comment: What do you mean by "just" experimental results and why do you give a _market report_ as reference?